# Select Neighboring X or Y Tiles

Tags: javascript, html5, html-canvas, isometric

I have a randomly generated set of tiles, and I am trying to select neighboring x or y tiles to perform functions on them based on if they are a certain value of tile, like so:

```
var IsometricMap = new Object();

      IsometricMap.tiles = [
        // "images/dirt.png",
        "images/dirtHigh.png",      // 0
        "images/grass.png",         // 1
        "images/water.png",         // 2
        "images/waterBeachCornerEast.png",  // 3
        "images/waterBeachCornerNorth.png", // 4
        "images/waterBeachCornerSouth.png", // 5
        "images/waterBeachCornerWest.png",  // 6
        "images/waterBeachEast.png",    // 7
        "images/waterBeachNorth.png",   // 8
        "images/waterBeachSouth.png",   // 9
        "images/waterBeachWest.png"]

var blockcount = 10;

    let generate_row = _=> Array(blockcount).fill().map(_=>Math.floor(Math.random()*3));
     IsometricMap.map = Array(blockcount).fill().map(generate_row);

    console.log(IsometricMap.map);


    for(let x = 0; x < IsometricMap.map.length; x++){

        for(let y = 0; y < IsometricMap.map.length; y++){


            if ((IsometricMap.map[x-1][y]) == 2) {
            //IF THE TILE IS WATER, DO ALL THIS:

            alert("SUCCESSFULLY SELECTED THE " + IsometricMap.map[x-1][y] + " TILE");

            //DONE WITH WATER TILES
            }


        }

    }
```

So far this is not yielding any results, its as if it cant find the tile I am trying to specify. Is there something wrong with my scope here?

Comment: Check https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775905/programming-logic-how-to-check-for-neighbors-in-a-grid&ved=2ahUKEwi37ZunlOriAhUDpFkKHXs9DBkQFjAAegQIBBAB&usg=AOvVaw3jL6NcAXcq8gmE7Q-3WzRk

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the program is throwing an exception for an out of range index? On the first pass of the loop, x-1 evaluates to -1.

Also I think Math.Random() returns values less than 1.0, so if you multiply by 3 you may only get values 0..2 out.

Comment: Which is fine, because 0..2 is exactly 3 possible values. Which is also a very handy since arrays are zero-based and 0..2 are indices of items in an array of length 3.

Answer (score 0):

Yea, this can be very annoying at times, but you have to check that the `[x - 1]` position exists. So your `if` statement becomes:

```js
    if (!!IsometricMap.map[x - 1] && IsometricMap.map[x - 1][y] == 2) {
        // Place your alert here
    }
```

Comment: Btw, don't test this, there are a hundred positions you are creating. This means that you can possibly have 100 alerts! Super annoying to test XD

Comment: This is the first time I see someone use a double exclamation mark instead of no exclamation marks at all. Is it considered good practice? Is it some kind of coding standard? I'm curious.

Comment: Well in truth, it will work without it. I just run into a bug once where I had to use double exclamation marks to make sure that an item already exists. JS can be weird at times.